# How to get an access token for the Cylance User API?

Tags: c#, authentication, token

I want to use the Cylance User API. I got C# sample code from them to use but they told me that they would not answer any questions.

This is the code I use for getting the Access token:

```
    private const int TimeoutSecs = 1800;
    private static void Main()
    {
        const string tenantId = "...";     // Tenant Id. The "..." are the real values of course. I just deleted them here because this is no info which belongs in the internet.
        const string appId = "...";
        const string appSecret = "...";    // Application secret.

        var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var jwtClaims = new JwtClaims
        {
            jti = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            iat = utcNow.ToUnixTimestamp(),
            exp = utcNow.AddSeconds(TimeoutSecs).ToUnixTimestamp(),
            iss = "http://cylance.com",
            tid = tenantId,
            sub = appId
        };

        try
        {
            var authToken = GenerateAuthorizationToken(jwtClaims, appSecret);
            Console.WriteLine($"\n[Authorization Token]\n{authToken}\n");

            var accessToken = GenerateAccessToken(authToken);
            Console.WriteLine($"\n[Access Token]\n{accessToken}\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string GenerateAuthorizationToken(JwtClaims jwtClaims, string appSecret)
    {
        if (jwtClaims == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jwtClaims));
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appSecret))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(appSecret));
        }

        var algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm();
        var serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
        var encoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
        var jwt = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, encoder);

        return jwt.Encode(jwtClaims, appSecret);
    }

    private static string GenerateAccessToken(string authToken)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authToken))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(nameof(authToken));
        }

        const string authEndpoint = "https://protectapi.cylance.com/auth/v2/token";

        var authRequest = new AuthTokenRequest
        {
            AuthToken = authToken
        };

        var authTask = authEndpoint
            .PostJsonAsync(authRequest)
            .ReceiveJson<AuthTokenResponse>();

        Task.WaitAll(authTask);

        var authResponse = authTask.Result;

        return authResponse.AccessToken;
    }
}


internal sealed class AuthTokenRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("auth_token")]
    public string AuthToken { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class AuthTokenResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}

internal sealed class JwtClaims
{
    public long exp { get; set; }
    public long iat { get; set; }
    public string iss { get; set; }
    public string sub { get; set; }
    public string jti { get; set; }
    public string tid { get; set; }
}
```

But when I call main an exception is thrown (The auth_token-text is larger in reality but I cut it because of the same reason like above):

```
POST https://protectapi.cylance.com/auth/v2/token failed with status code 401 (Unauthorized).
Request body:
{"auth_token":"ey...
                    ...wQQ"}
Response body:
{"message":"Invalid JWT payload"}
```

Regarding to the resopnse message "Invalid JWT payload" I think I have done something wrong in the creation of the AuthorizationToken but I cant figure out what.

Comment: You are probably failing the SSL/TLS authorization.  Recently a lot of server stopped using TLS1.1 and you must use TLS1.2.  So either windows is missing a security update or the JWT dll is old and you need to use a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the url of the autentfification endpoint was wrong. So this is the correct line (in function: GenerateAccessToken)

`const string authEndpoint = "https://protectapi-euc1.cylance.com/auth/v2/token";`

because I am from Europe - Central.

This is the whole list of Service Endpoints as described in the documentation:

- Asia-Pacific - North https://protectapi-apne1.cylance.com/
- Asia-Pacific - Southeast https://protectapi-au.cylance.com/
- Europe - Central https://protectapi-euc1.cylance.com/
- North America https://protectapi.cylance.com/
- South America https://protectapi-sae1.cylance.com/
- US Government https://protectapi.us.cylance.com/